# Smartsheet API Dropdown List

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, smartsheet-api

When accessing a sheet on Smartsheet using their C# API, would one be able to programmatically find the attributes of a drop down list for a column that has one? I haven't been able to find anything hinting at it on their developers page, but maybe I've missed it all these times. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `options` contains a list of available drop down options, or `contactOptions` if the column type is `CONTACT_LIST`. Is that what you are asking?